# LinkedIn OAuth: How to access Location and Positions info from LinkedIn Users?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Based on [LinkedIn Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/fields):

> The following selection of profile fields are available to all
> LinkedIn developers:
>
> - Basic Profile Fields
> - Location Fields
> - Position Fields

However, when creating a LinkedIn OAuth app (https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps), I only get access to Basic Profile Fields (through the r_liteprofile scope).

How do I enable access to Location and Position Fields (and what are the corresponding scopes)? My intention is to avoid having to request [Partner Program](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products) membership as (1) I dont need as much info and (2) it takes a while to get approved.

Thanks in advance, Miguel.